# How to re-connect to XMPP after Network Failure to Same Room - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xmpp, xmppframework

I have implemented XMPP chat in my application.

I have set up my stream as:

```
 - (void)setupStream {

_xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
[_xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];


//Reconnection Setup

self.xmppReconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[self.xmppReconnect activate:_xmppStream];
[self.xmppReconnect addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
self.xmppReconnect.autoReconnect = YES;

self.xmppAutoPing = [[XMPPAutoPing alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
self.xmppAutoPing.pingInterval = 2.f; // default is 60
self.xmppAutoPing.pingTimeout = 10.f; // default is 10
[self.xmppAutoPing activate:_xmppStream];
[self.xmppAutoPing addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];




[_xmppStream setHostName:kChatUrl];
[_xmppStream setHostPort:kPort];


_xmppMUC = [[XMPPMUC alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[_xmppMUC activate:_xmppStream];

[_xmppMUC addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

}
```

> The problem is whenever Network Loses it connection i am not able to re-Connect. I have to disconnect the xmpp and make connection Call again.

Although I have implemented these Delegates:

```
  #pragma mark - Reconenction Delegate

  - (void)xmppReconnect:(XMPPReconnect *)sender didDetectAccidentalDisconnect:(SCNetworkConnectionFlags)connectionFlags
  {
     NSLog(@"Disconnected"); //Called after 1 min

  }
  - (BOOL)xmppReconnect:(XMPPReconnect *)sender shouldAttemptAutoReconnect:(SCNetworkConnectionFlags)connectionFlags
 {
   NSLog(@"Reconnecting");
   return YES;
 }


 #pragma mark - AutoPing Delegate

  - (void)xmppAutoPingDidSendPing:(XMPPAutoPing *)sender
  {
    NSLog(@"xmppAutoPingDidSendPing");
    }

  - (void)xmppAutoPingDidReceivePong:(XMPPAutoPing *)sender
  {
    NSLog(@"xmppAutoPingDidReceivePong");
   }


  - (void)xmppAutoPingDidTimeout:(XMPPAutoPing *)sender
 {
    NSLog(@"xmppAutoPingDidTimeout");
   }
```

Even after this I am not able to make Reconnection to previous room. I always end up by joining new Room.

```
Here is my Disconnection Method
  [self goOffline];
[_xmppStream disconnect];
 [_xmppStream removeDelegate:self];
_xmppStream = nil;
```

**Edit** My code to join a room

```
  - (void)joinMultiUserChatRoom:(NSString *)newRoomName
 {
XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:newRoomName];

if(self.prevRoomName && self.prevRoomName.length>0)
    newRoomName = self.prevRoomName;


self.prevRoomName = newRoomName;



XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomMemoryStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];
XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc]
                      initWithRoomStorage:roomMemoryStorage
                      jid:roomJID
                      dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom activate:_xmppStream];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:kNickName history:nil];



 }
```

Comment: `XMPPReconnect` only autoconnects the client, nothing beyond that. How do you join new room after reconnection?

Comment: @Fujia I simply call the connect method...after Disconnecting

Comment: You don't need to call that as `XMPPReconnect` manages that for you. You may re-enter rooms with exactly the same room JID.

Comment: @Fujia I edited my code.I have to save the JID or roomName. And after disconnect how can I pass this id/name. And suppose connection fails then which method should I call to join any room.

Comment: You can start joining rooms after authentication is successful, in this delegate method `- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender`.

Comment: @Fujia yes this is called but by which mehtod I connect to previous room. and what if that room is closed. Can I connect to some other if previous was anavailabel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117588/discussion-between-rahulmishra-and-fujia).